# jQuery - Swapping button background color with text color on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a jQuery function that will grab the background color, text color, and border color of a button and swap them on mouseenter and then set them back to normal on mouseleave. This is then being animation using CSS transitions.

The problem that I'm running in to is that if you move the mouse on and off of the button very quickly it grabs the colors mid transition and sets the background, text, and border to the wrong colors.

EDIT: For clarification, I cannot set the color values myself. Since this is for a WordPress theme, the button colors are set by the content creator and not myself. So then need to be identified in jQuery(hence the variables that grab the property on mouseenter).

I have tried a few different things but did not come to a solution.

Here is my current code(EDITED to include HTML and CSS examples):

**HTML**

```
<button>
Test Button
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  background: purple;
  border: 0.1em solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
button.mouseenter(function() {

    var color = $(this).css('color');
    var background = $(this).css('background-color');
    var border = $(this).css('border-color');

    $(this).css({
        'color' : background,
        'background-color' : color,
        'border-color' : background
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'color' : color,
            'background-color' : background,
            'border-color' : border
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT: Here is a jsfiddle with a working example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8dw3anyq/

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you not using a simple `css:hover`?

Comment: Because this is on a WordPress website where the button color can be chosen by the content editor, so I do not have a way to set it in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this toke me a while to solve I got rather busy over the last few days but I think I have a working solution to this now!

https://jsfiddle.net/nv5L9s2d/14/

I'm sure it isn't the most effective solution and am more then happy to take any possible improvements on board.

**HTML**

```
<button class="buttonChange OldButton" index="0">Change color</button>
<button class="buttonChange NewButton" index="1">Change color 2</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 8px 14px;
 font-size: 15px;

 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.OldButton {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
} 

.NewButton {
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var changeButtons = $('.buttonChange');

console.log(changeButtons);

var colorOrgArray = []; 
var backgroundOrgArray = [];
var borderOrgArray = [];

$.each(changeButtons, function (index, div) {
 console.log('loop');

 colorOrgArray.push($(this).css('color'));
 backgroundOrgArray.push($(this).css('background-color'));
 borderOrgArray.push($(this).css('border-color'));

 // $(this).addEventListener('mouseenter', ManageButtonHover, false);
 // $(this).addEventListener('mouseleave', ManageButtonHoverOut, false);

 });

 for (var i = 0; i < changeButtons.length; i++) {
  console.log('loop 2');

  changeButtons[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', ManageButtonHover, false);
  changeButtons[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', ManageButtonHoverOut, false);
 }

 console.log(backgroundOrgArray);

 function ManageButtonHover () {
   console.log('Entered ManageButtonHover');

   var color = $(this).css('color');
   var background = $(this).css('background-color');
   var border = $(this).css('border-color');

   $(this).css({
    'color' : background,
    'background-color' : color,
    'border-color' : background
   });
}

function ManageButtonHoverOut() {
 var _index =  $(event.target).attr("index");

 console.log('Entered ManageButtonHoverOut: ' + _index);

 $(this).css({
   'color' : colorOrgArray[_index],
   'background-color' : backgroundOrgArray[_index],
   'border-color' : borderOrgArray[_index]
 });
}
```

Comment: This is really great, thank you so much for all your effort! Unfortunately this doesn't quite work for this situation. It looks like the <button> elements have to have the index attribute on them for this solution to work. I cannot add that to all of the buttons on the website as this is a WordPress website and some of them are automatically generated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5b3rkx87/48/ @MichaelAbraham I think this should solve that issue :)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like we end up with the same issue where repeated mouseenter and mouseleave events cause the colors to change and blend together

Comment: Sorry made a stupid mistake and made `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` call the same function lol 1step forward 5 back haha try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/eu2pywa4/4/ @MichaelAbraham

Comment: That works amazingly! Thank you so much for the assistance on this one.

Comment: No worries, happy to help and to learn more about jquery!